# Warum sagt man "Wir haben einen Platten" obwohl Platte weiblich oder sächlich ist?

Tags: translation, gender, article

[Nach Kanoo Platte](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?input=Platten&service=canooNet) ist nicht ein Substantiv adjektival, und muss natürlich im Singular sein. Warum sagt man nicht:

> "Wir haben eine Platte?"

oder

> "Wir haben ein Platten"?

Comment: Die/ eine Platte und der/ ein Platten sind verschiedene Dinge.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are two different things.

> Wir haben eine Platte.

*We have a plate/disc/record.*

**Die Platte** is a shortening from *die Langspielplatte*, a 33rpm long play record, as opposed to the older 78rpm records. But *die Platte* applies to both 33rpm 2·20m records and 45rpm 2·3m records. The latter is also called *die Single*, or [*die Scheibe*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJGNL3KuI5A). 45rpm 2·10m records are called *die Maxi-Single*.

And of course there are other meanings for *die Platte* as well.

> Heute gibt es kalte Platte.

*Today we have a cold buffet.*

> Nimm den Kessel von der Platte!

*Take the kettle from the stove!*

---

> Wir haben einen Platten.

This is a shortening for

> Wir haben einen platten Reifen.

*We have a flat tire.*

And because it's *der platte Reifen*, it becomes **der Platte**.

Comment: I see, so it is one of those weird adjectival nouns and will also be declined in a sentence then.

Comment: http://cinetropolis.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-t-anderson-banner.jpg

Comment: »And because it's *der platte Reifen*, it becomes **der Platte**.« – it actually becomes **der Platten** http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Platten

Comment: Dann gibt es offensichtlich beides. Mir käme *der Platten* eher süddeutsch vor.

Comment: was ist der Unterschied zwischen beides und beide?

Comment: @Janka Es fällt mir extrem schwer, auch nur irgendeinen Nachweis zu finden, dass „der Platte“ für einen Platten verwendet wird…

Comment: Nur der  Vollständigkeit halber: es gibt auch "die Platte" als Kurzform für den Plattenbau.

Comment: "Die Platte is a shortening from die Langspielplatte" - first or and foremost, *die Platte* is an arbitrary flat and hard object. Yes, it appears in plenty of compounds which, in turn, often get shortened again to *Platte* if the context is clear. Nonetheless, it is a rather generic word, so it seems a bit odd to immediately point out a specific meaning (that, by the way, is by no means the first one that would come to my mind).

Comment: @cgnieder: Gibt es denn Nachweise, dass "der Platten" für einen platten Reifen verwendet wird (außer der ehrlich gesagt für meine Ohren sehr fragwürdig klingenden Behauptung des Dudens)?

Comment: @cgnieder: Es ist zugegebenermaßen sehr schwer, irgendwelche definitiven Vorkommen aufzuspüren (das Wort taucht einfach sehr selten im Nominativ auf), aber zumindest gibt es in einem Buch den Satz ["Eher ein Platter an meinem Wagen"](https://books.google.de/books?id=T8cIBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT76&lpg=PT76&dq=%22ein+platter+an+meinem+wagen%22&source=bl&ots=YuO7e0BjRD&sig=10wXOUVfLM0mwnE0hd0H5eDFeJg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS0ITvqPDTAhVCDiwKHeEGBYcQ6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=%22ein%20platter%20an%20meinem%20wagen%22&f=false). Die Autorin wandte hier offenbar die gewöhnlichen Regeln der Adjektivdeklination an, ...

Comment: ... was mit bestimmtem Artikel die Form "der Platte" ergeben hätte.

Comment: "Tut mir leid, ich bin zu spät, ich hatte einen Platten  - Tja, ein Platten, dumme Sache" ist vollkommen gängig in Süddeutschland (das ist natürlich kein Beweis). Was der Nominativ davon sein mag, ist wohl einigermaßen schwer nachweisbar, mein Gefühl sagt mir, es sei "der Platten" (und das ist auch kein Beweis).

Comment: unrelated: "Die Platte" ist auch umgangssprachlich gebräuchlich für "die Glatze"

Comment: Wenn es denn nur süddeutsch wäre, müsste die Google-Bildersuche <<"eine Platte" Auto>> mehr sinnvolle Bilder liefern als <<"einen Platten" Auto>>. Sorry, aber ich glaube nicht, dass das Ergebnis dieser Googlesuche in Berlin groß anders ist.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz Ich bin dadurch verwirrt. Auto ist sächlich daher sind beide falsch

Comment: @user135711 Auto dient nur als zweiter Suchbegriff. Sonst würden nicht relevante Ergebnisse kommen.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz ahh, ich sehe.

Comment: @user135711 ich sehe ist ein Anglizismus und wird so im Deutschen nicht verwendet. Entweder "ahh, ich verstehe" oder besser "ah, verstehe". - Punkt ist aber dass "der Platten" deutschlandweit verwendet wird und korrekt ist.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz ahh, verstehe

Comment: @MaestroGlanz: "<<"eine Platte" Auto>>" - "*eine* Platte" stand glaube ich gar nicht zur Debatte, lediglich "ein Platter" bzw. "der Platte". Hier in Südwestdeutschland ist mir "der Platten" jedenfalls noch nie begegnet und es klingt für mich auch ausschließlich wie ein Grammatikfehler.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper stimmt, hab mich verlesen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper eine Internetsuche nach `"der platten" auto` liefert mir auf den ersten paar Seiten wenigstens ein paar Treffer in Büchern, während `"der platte" auto` mir nur Genitivformen liefert also würde ich sagen, ja es gibt neben dem Duden noch weitere Hinweise. Und da wir schon bei anekdotischen Hinweisen sind: hier in Südwestdeutschland ist *mir* „der Platten“ durchaus schon begegnet :)

Comment: @cgnieder: Ok, dann ist wohl beides in Verwendung. Ein paar der auffindbaren Beispiele für die Variante mit dem flektierten Adjektiv sind ["Der Platte ist der Klassiker aller Pannen"](https://www.gletschersau.de/2015-10-06_schlauch_und_reifen/), ["Pannensicherer Fahrradreifen: Der 'Platte' ist passee"](https://www.test.de/Pannensicherer-Fahrradreifen-Der-Platte-ist-passee-1107034-0/), ["Der Platte ist bei ca. 110 km/Std aufgetreten"](http://www.motor-talk.de/forum/reifenpanne-mit-runflat-reifen-t5419524.html).

Answer (score 0):

Some additional information:

"Der Platten" is the (actually incorrect) nominalization of the adjective "platt".

Like in "Möchtest du eine schwarze oder grüne Olive?" (no capitals) and "Ich möchte eine Grüne."